# How do the arguments of a decorated function work?

Tags: python, python-decorators

```py
var = float(input('Enter a number: '))


def math_test(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        func(var)
    return wrapper


@math_test
def times10(x):
    print(x * 10)


times10()
```

Why is it that when I call the function `times10()`, that I don't need to put the argument `var` in the brackets?

When I didn't type the argument `var` when I called `func()` I got an error saying requiring positional argument `x`...so when I put `var` in `times10()` I got the same error.

However when I placed the argument in `func()` it worked fine.

Shouldn't the wrapper function know that the argument in `times10()`, which would be `var`, should also be the argument in `func()`?

Edit:

```py
var = float(input('Enter a number: '))


def math_test(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@math_test
def times10(x):
    print(x * 10)

times10(var)
```

Comment: "Apologies in advance for not being able to add the image inline, I don't have enough reputation." - you should post code as code-formatted text, not as an image.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to edit that.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I fixed it.

Comment: @ddejohn how did make all the code in the main body look like that? was it ``` ```

Comment: The reason your code works at all is because `var` is a global variable. What you're supposed to do here is 1) pass `args` and `kwargs` to the wrapped function, `func()` and 2) `return` the call to `func()`.

Comment: For inline highlighting `like this`, you use a single backtick. You can also see what I did by editing your post yourself, which will show the raw markdown.

Comment: By pass `args` and `kwargs` to the wrapped function, do you mean func(*args, **kwargs) ? And then instead of return wrapper, return func?

Comment: Return `func(*args, **kwargs)` from `wrapper` and return `wrapper` from `math_test`.

Comment: The examples here are exemplary of the choices you have: https://sanicframework.org/en/guide/best-practices/decorators.html#templates

Comment: ohhh. Ok that makes more sense now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This decorated function:

```
@math_test
def times10(x):
    print(x * 10)
```

Will be translated to:

```
times10 = math_test(times10)
```

Which means `times10` is now equivalent to:

```
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    func(var)
```

Where the callable `func` points to the original implementation of `times10`. To further visualize this, think of it as like this:

```
def times10(*args, **kwargs):
    def original_times10(x):
        print(x * 10)
    original_times10(var)
```

- If you call `func(var)` which is synonymous above to `original_times10(var)` then it would work since `original_times10` is passed `var` which would be put the argument `x`.
- If you call `func()` which is synonymous above to `original_times10()`, it will obviously not work because `original_times10` requires an input `x` but yet you didn't pass it anything.

---

Note that what you are trying to do is strictly passing a fixed argument `var` to the original implementation of `times10`:

```
func(var)
```

Depending on your usecase, I believe what you should be doing is passing the actual arguments:

```
func(*args, **kwargs)
```

This way, whatever you pass to the decorated function of `times10` would be passed to the original implementation of `times10`.